# Get association element that has a parameter

Tags: associations, filtering

Say I have an `Association` of the form:

```
assoc = <|first->"abc", second[param]->"xyz"|>
```

Now to access `first`, all I have to do is call `assoc[first]`. Now the problem is that I need an easy way to access `second`, but without knowing the parameter (which is here `param`).

Is it possible to use something in the form `assoc[second]` with some minor modification? Or do I have to write my own function that manipulates `Keys[assoc]` to find `second`?

In short, the question is: What's the easiest way to access `second` and get the information in `param`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
FilterRules[assoc, second[_]][[1, 1, 1]]
(*param*)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can `Select` from the `Keys` of the `Association` the elements with `Head` equal to `second` and then pick out the parameter from `second`.

```
Select[Head@# === second &]@Keys[assoc] /. second[p_] -> p
(* {param} *)
```

Hope this helps.

---

**Update** with version that uses only *key* functions.

```
KeySelect[Head@# === second &] /* KeyMap[Replace[_[p_] -> p]] /* Keys@assoc
(* {param} *)
```